# ASP .NET MVC - Adding text from TextBox to table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can i add something to the list and display it in table in ASP .NET CORE MVC? I'm trying to do simple URL shortener, but I can't even pass full link to the view.

My **model**:

```
 public class Link
 {
    public string FullLink { get; set; }
    public string ShortenedLink { get; set; }


    public static List<Link> _list = new List<Link>();

}
```

My **controller**:

```
public class LinkController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(Link._list);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Add(string link)
    {
        Link._list.Add(new Link { FullLink = link });
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

**My view:**

```
@model List<UrlShortener.Models.Link>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Link", FormMethod.Post))
        {
        @Html.TextBox("myTextBox");
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
        }
    <div>
        <table>
           @foreach (var item in Model)
           {
            <tr><td>@item.FullLink</td></tr>
               }
</table>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Can someone explain me what am I doing wrong that after clicking "Add" button nothing happens?

Comment: You textbox is not binding to anything in your model. If you want the value in the textbox in the post method, then its `public IActionResult Add(string myTextBox)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your form what your textbox represents.

Instead of using "myTextBox" for the `name` parameter of your textbox, give it the name (*link* in your example) of the parameter in your controller method, `public IActionResult Add(string link)`, you are binding your form to.

In short, you need to change the textbox declaration in your view to this:
`@Html.TextBox("link")`

*Note: the semicolon after the `Html.TextBox(...)` tag is unnecessary*